# Binding to a collection in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a problem trying to bind a DataGrid to a List, or to a Dictionary.
If I set DataContext to an object, and set ItemSource to a List property of that object, I get DataGrid populated with List count, in case of a List, why? How can I bind properly to a List, and how to a Dictionary?

```
List<string> con = new List<string>();
        con.Add("aaaddd");
        con.Add("bbb");
        this.DataContext = con;

<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="104" HorizontalAlignment="Left"          Margin="34,171,0,0" Name="dg" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="421" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

And I get populated with

Length
6
3

Why? And how to bind to a Dictionary?

Comment: There is no `DataGridView` control in WPF as far as i'm aware... If you mean `DataGrid` instead, you usually bind like `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` where `Items` is a `List` (though you might want to use `ObservableCollection`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you have set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `True` on your dataGrid.

When AutoGenerateColumns is set to true than **columns are auto generated based on the properties exposed by the underlying object** which is in your case is **string** which only exposes single property i.e. **Length**.

In case you want to get the value of string, you need to set that property to false and provide your own columns collection. This will work -

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value"
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                Binding="{Binding}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, that's the answer I was looking for, works like a charm! Just one more question, if you need to bind your DataGrid to a Dictionary, but that it acts like Observable, how would you realize that? Thanks, ones again.

Comment: You need to create an ObservableDictionary in case you want it to be observable. Google for it you will get lots of implementation. Just in case you can look over these [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx) and [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/).

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comment, I think you're refering to WPF's `DataGrid` Control.
If you're setting the list object to the `DataContext` then just `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` this will bind to the `DataContext` root which is your list object.

Comment: Yes, its DataGrid, sorry, it was late. I've done what you said, and the same thing happens, I probably made an error, but I don't see where. I'll edit my question with an example.